# Renaming File in Library "Invalid File Name" Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

One of my users has a simple SharePoint 2010 library where they store PDFs with some metadata. Problem is, when someone tries to rename the file, by editing the `Name` field, SharePoint gives an error that the new name is invalid. Strangely, once the error message is close and the page refreshed, the name **has changed** despite the error saying the opposite.

The same behavior occurs in Explorer View.

There are no special characters in the file names, nor is the filename too long. Versioning is disabled, checking out files is not required.

Log files:

> 03/29/2016 15:58:54.51    w3wp.exe (SPSTSTWF02:0x154C)    0x19CC  SharePoint Foundation   Database    d0d6    High    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = 256.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResult()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock)    19495cb1-9004-444f-a736-265a1d3d766c
>
> 03/29/2016 15:58:54.51    w3wp.exe (SPSTSTWF02:0x154C)    0x19CC  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    Invalid file name.  The file name you specified could not be used.  It may be the name of an existing file or directory, or you may not have permission to access the file. 19495cb1-9004-444f-a736-265a1d3d766c
>
> 03/29/2016 15:58:54.51    w3wp.exe (SPSTSTWF02:0x154C)    0x19CC  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Invalid file name.  The file name you specified could not be used.  It may be the name of an existing file or directory, or you may not have permission to access the file.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)    19495cb1-9004-444f-a736-265a1d3d766c

Comment: Can the user download the file?

Comment: yes they can! no issue downloading.

Comment: Can you do a Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx -Identity Database, have the user repro, run Clear-SPLogLevel, then Merge-SPLogLevel for the period of time the user was repro'ing, and finally update your question with that log file?

Comment: Thanks Trevor. In SP Central Admin, what level of logs should be turned on to get this level of detail?

Comment: The cmdlets I provided set/unset the logging level.

Comment: Ok thank you. Sorry I have never run a cmd like this before. I imagine I use this in SP Management Shell? From your post, what pieces do I need to modify? Apologies...

Comment: Yes, use the SharePoint Management Shell. Once open, run `Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx`. Wait for the cmdlet to complete. Notate the time down to the second-ish, then have the user repro. Notate the time once the user has completed the repro. Run `Clear-SPLogLevel` to re-set the logging level. Next, merge the log file. `Merge-SPLogFile -Path C:\output.log -StartTime "3/24/16 09:20:31" -EndTime "3/24/16 09:20:56"`, as an example to merge between today at 9:20 AM between 31 and 56 seconds.

Comment: Updated with log info

Comment: Thanks, but there should be additional logging besides what you posted, in addition, the format here isn't the best. Could you host the actual log file on a file service (OneDrive, Dropbox, etc.) and provide the link instead? Can you also provide the source name of the file and destination name of the file, as well as the name of the Document Library in which they reside?

Comment: Another weird thing discovered, if I rename the filename down to two (2) characters, eg."99"I get no error. And having done that, I can now rename the file back to exactly what it was before eg"AC-007-1230" and the errors have vanished on this one item.

Comment: Ah, I see what is going on. You're exceeding the path limit of 256 characters (that is what the tinyint value is). We would need the full ULS log to determine what is being passed to the SQL query, though, not just the exception in the stack trace.

Comment: But if it's exceeding the limit, why does setting the name down to two characters "immunize" it against future errors? I can then rename the file to something much longer without issue. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: That's why I asked for the entire log rather than just the exceptions. Can't tell you without additional information prior to the exception.

Comment: I apologize, I haven't been attempting to hide key information. I am simply a new employee where I work and was trying to avoid doing anything that they might not approve of. I will investigate with my superior if they have any concerns about my sharing the log.

Answer (score 0):

One thing it could be: the new file name matches a file with the same URL in the recycle bin. So, the file can actually be renamed, but its name conflicts with the name of a recycled file.
Note: this idea has been inspired by reading the first comment at: http://sharepointmalaya.blogspot.fr/2011/02/delete-corrupted-list-using-stsadm.html

Comment: Good idea! Sadly it didn't help me. :(